# C# List sorting with For Loop

Tags: c#, sorting, for-loop

I have these two `List<string>[]` the first one `subj_cat1_id` contains a list of IDs and the second list `AssignedSubjectsID`contains the IDs that are already assigned to the students. I need to loop into the first list `subj_cat1_id` and remove from it all IDs that are equally found in the `AssignedSubjectsID` list.

I'm using the following algorithm:

```
for (int i = 0; i != subject_cat1_id[0].Count; i++)
                {
                    foreach (string id in AssignedSubjectsID[0])
                    {
                        if (subject_cat1_id[0][i] == id)
                        {
                            //add assigned subjects to student subject listbox
                            lst_sud_subjects.Items.Add(subject_cat1[0][i] + " (" + subjshort1 + ")");
                            ObjCache.SubjectAllocation.AssignedToID.Add(subject_cat1_id[0][i]);

                            //remove id and subj name from list
                            subject_cat1_id[0].RemoveAt(i);
                            subject_cat1[0].RemoveAt(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

That's driving me since yesterday is that the outer For loop seems to be skipping IDs found in the List `subject_cat1_id`.

Here's a test case:

```
subject_cat1_id contains IDs 1 to 22.
AssignedSubjectsID contains IDs 17,16,10,8,14 in that order.
```

The algorithm loops through 1-16, skips ID 17 and goes straight to ID 18.

My brain is not working anymore so any help would be well appreciated.

Thanks ~

Comment: Rule #1 when working with lists, don't edit the list while you're looping through it.

Comment: telling me why would help. what's the best approach to tackle this issue in your opinion? ~ thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with Linq:

```
var remaining=subj_cat1_id[0].Except(AssignedSubjectsID[0]);
```

(I'm matching the posted code which only does this for the first item in each array.)

Answer (score 2):

`subject_cat1_id[0].RemoveAt(i);` removes the element you are currently looking at with your outer loop's index `i`. Thus all elements in that collection move one position towards the beginning of the list.

```
int i = 1;
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].RemoveAt(i)
```

results in

```
['a', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Thus for instance, the `c` which was at index `2` before is now at index `1`. Before the next iteration of the loop starts, `i` is incremented by 1. Continuing the previous example you now have

```
['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'].RemoveAt(2)
```

Which removes the `d` and is, obviously, not what you want, because you skipped the `c`.

Thus @FrankerZ's comment not to manipulate a list, while iterating it. Or if you must do, do it properly. Best practice is, to do it in reverse direction, because you already handled the later indexes.

```
for (int i = subject_cat1_id[0].Count-i; i >=0; i--) {
    ....
}
```